# Removing sap from an old railing

Tags: wood

I have an old railing that has hard, crystallized sap that has seeped through. I'd estimate it could be 75 years old. How can I remove the sap without damaging the finish?

Answer (score 2):

If the sap is really hard, you should be able to knock it off with a quick swipe with a scraper. The finish underneath might be compromised, though.

If its still a bit gooey, you might try hitting it with a spurt of compressed air from a can to cool it down.